# multiplying matrices in C (-1.#IND)

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

I'm debugging a program written in C using Visual Studio,
when I reached statement of multiplying two matrices,
I got unexpected value `-1.#IND000000000000` for all
elements of result matrix.

what does it mean?

following function used for matrix multiplying.

```
extern void matmul(const char *tr, int n, int k, int m, double alpha,
                   const double *A, const double *B, double beta, double *C)
{
    double d;
    int i,j,x,f=tr[0]=='N'?(tr[1]=='N'?1:2):(tr[1]=='N'?3:4);

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        for (j=0;j<k;j++) {
            d=0.0;
            switch (f) {
                case 1: for (x=0;x<m;x++) d+=A[i+x*n]*B[x+j*m]; break;
                case 2: for (x=0;x<m;x++) d+=A[i+x*n]*B[j+x*k]; break;
                case 3: for (x=0;x<m;x++) d+=A[x+i*m]*B[x+j*m]; break;
                case 4: for (x=0;x<m;x++) d+=A[x+i*m]*B[j+x*k]; break;
            }
            if  (beta==0.0) 
                C[i+j*n]=alpha*d;
            else 
                C[i+j*n]=alpha*d+beta*C[i+j*n];
        }
}

matmul("NN",n,1,m,1.0,A,y,0.0,Ay); /* Ay=A*y */
```

Comment: This doesn't really seem like a duplicate. Of course sqrt(-number) results in NaN, but matrix multiplication would be just muls and adds.

Comment: @chux, I add multiplication function `matmul` inside 3rd `for` loop variable `d` get this unexpected value.

Comment: Post, though better, does not show how you "... got unexpected value -1.#IND000000000000".  What was the contents of `A, B, C,` when `matmul()` was called. There is no print, no sample input.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: If it's any of the IEEE special case quiet not-a-numbers, you may get that kind of output.  Your code on its own wouldn't cause that (you don't have division by zero, sqrt of a negative number, and I don't think you can get infinity for multiplying a really large number by another really large number), so your best bet is to check your inputs.  If any of your inputs are quiet not-a-numbers, the result would propagate through your arithmetic.

Comment: Actually, at least on my processor, you *can* get infinity by multiplying two large numbers, so if your inputs aren't themselves infinite, then you're multiplying numbers large enough to get there.

Comment: Dear @Scott Mermelstein, thanks for your suggestion, there is bug that cause one of input before passing to multyplying functions gets `QNaN` value.